# How to do a DropDownListFor where the options have ids?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to replicate a simple thing when it is done in straight up html, where a dropdown designed for the user to select a color has select options with colored backgrounds. By assigning id type css one can easily get this to work.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #red {background: #ff0000;}
  #orange {background: #ffaa00;}
  #yellow {background: #ffff00;}
  #green {background: #00ff50;}
  #purple {background: #9932CD;}
  #blue {background: #0000ff;}
  #brown {background: #8B4513;}
</style>

<body>
<div id=container>
    <select id='selected' onchange='changeColor(this.value);'>
        <option id='red' value='#ff0000'>Red</option>
        <option id='orange' value='#ffaa00'>Orange</option>
        <option id='yellow' value='#ffff00'>Yellow</option>
        <option id='green' value='#00ff50'>Green</option>
        <option id='purple' value='#9932CD'>Purple</option>
        <option id='blue' value='#0000ff'>Blue</option>
        <option id='brown' value='#8B4513'>Brown</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
```

I would like to do this in MVC4 using a DropDownListFor() but don't know how to insert the id attribute/value pairs in the options. Here is my current mvc code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => Model.Item.Id,
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Id", "Name", Model.Item.Id),
    new { @class = "selectStatus", onchange = "changeColor(this)" })
```

The model here is a class with Id and Name properties.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would hope the answer is simple, but it eludes me. I thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

on your controller build your drop down list and assing it to your model

```
List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var temp in YourRecords){
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.Text, Value = temp.Value });
}

ViewModel.DropDownList = ls;
```

then on your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item.Id, Model.DropDownList, new { @class = "selectStatus"})
```

Comment: And where in here did you assign the 'color' id values, as I showed above?

Comment: text is the field that will show up for the end user and value is the value for the item,  that is what will be returned to the controller as the selected item.